# How to get metadata of end points level from any services like wsdl url's

Tags: c#

I am trying to get meta of any wcf, asmx services with endpoints. I am getting meta at service level. but, not getting methods and their signature at end point levels of any wsdl ulr. can any one help for this.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your expect result to make your question more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using visual studio?If Yes,

In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the project that you want to add the service to, and then click Add Service Reference.

The Add Service Reference dialog box appears.

In the Address box, enter the URL for the service, and then click Go to search for the service. 
In the Services list, expand the node for the service that you want to use and select an entity set.

In the Namespace box, enter the namespace that you want to use for the reference.

Click OK to add the reference to the project.

A service client (proxy) is generated, and metadata that describes the service is added to the app.config file.

Comment: Not by adding reference, without adding reference when we give wsdl URL i want to get metadata using "MetadataExchangeClient" class in c#.